# How do you call a partition of a totally ordered set that....

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, set-partition

A partition of a set S is a collection P={B<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>,...,B<sub>k</sub>}  of subset of S such that for each i, j, ∈ {1,2,...,k}:

1. B<sub>i</sub> ≠ ∅
2. B<sub>i</sub> ⋂ B<sub>j</sub> ≠ ∅
3. B<sub>1</sub> ⋃ B<sub>2</sub> ⋃...⋃ B<sub>k</sub> = S

now if S is a totally ordered set and P is also equipped with a partial order ≼ how do you call a partition that meets the following additional condition?

for x ∈ B<sub>i</sub>, y x ∈ B<sub>j</sub>, if x<y then i≤j (or B <sub>i</sub> ≼ B<sub>j</sub>)

For example if S= {1, 2, 3, 4} we can have the following partitions of S into two subsets:

1/234, 12/34 and 123/4 (but not 13/24 nor 14/23)

I've come accross the following definitions: monotone partition, consecutive partition...but I don't seem to find a commonly accepted terminology nor any body of litterature that would study these ...  (I know it is subset of partitions and non-crossing partitions)

Any directions, hints for me?

Many thanks

---

P.S: to give a bit of context, I wanted to study this type of partitions in details (their lattice structure, total number given binomials as suggested by Donald S. etc...)

Comment: you meant $B_i\cap B_j=\emptyset $?

Comment: I would call them compositions, cause they seem to be in bijection with compositions of $n$ (ordered integer partitions) with each part $>0.$

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error. I saw the term composition coined a few time (https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Totally_ordered_set) but I was not sure if it was widely used or not, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome. yes, bijection with those would be $A_i=\bigcup _{j\leq i}B_j.$ Although, I was thinking more in their cardinals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your p.s I think you would appreciate the following discussion.

Notice that your partitions, because there is an order inherit from the line, are completely characterize by the size of the sets. So, a partition of your interest say $\pi =\{B_1,B_2,\cdots ,B_k\}$ is such that $B_i=[x_1+\cdots +x_{i-1}+1,x_1+\cdots +x_{i-1}+x_i]\cap \mathbb{Z}$ where $x_0=0$ so the size of $|B_i|=x_i.$ in this way, the number of these partitions is $$|\{(x_1,\cdots ,x_k):\sum _{i=1}^kx_i=n,x_i>0\}|=\binom{n-1}{k-1},$$
which adds up to $2^{n-1}$ if you add over the number of parts. That is why is not very interesting to compute them and also the motivation to call them **compositions.**
In terms of the order structure that they inherit from the partitions you can check that the refinement looks like the Boolean lattice for $[n-1].$
Notice that a very similar concept that is very well studied is the concept of flag. The partitions that you describe are what happens to basis elements in flags of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: I appreciate it indeed! thanks for bringing that up.
I came to the same  conclusions about the number of partition and Boolean lattice. I also noticed that the RGF is layered (and weakly increasing) which is another "boring" results I guess. But this will serve as a basis for future work. I am going to learn more about flag, that sounds like an interesting perspective. I guess you and Donald answered my question. Not sure which one to tick...

Comment: @torino You are welcome. Hopefully you can go on in the research and find cool stuff.

Answer (score 1):

$13/2$ avoiding partitions. This means that we cannot have $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$ & $ a_1,a_3 \in B_i, a_2 \in B_j$ ($i \neq j$)

With this restriction we get binomials and without this we get stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: I got more results in litterature using the term "13/2 avoiding partitions" which is great. Thanks!  I feel a bit frusrated that we define these by what they are not as opposed to what they are. I am also surprised that these are not more studied given the number of applications they could have but it must be me struggling to navigate litterature. Or maybe an ordered partition of an order set suffices as definition?